# Why ssh connection failed?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, connection, putty, vmware-server

I have an ubuntu virtual machine with vmware server 2.0.2 and my pc windows xp.

The problem is that I have all the time a message "ssh connection failed".

My firewall is disabled, all protection which could be stop the connection are disabled
I haven't done an update or upgrade.

So, i don't understand why ? maybe a automatic update on ubuntu who fail the connection ?
becaus i don't think its cause by the software, because i have the same message with putty,winscp...

Comment: was the ssh connection ''ever'' working?

Answer (score 2):

1) Use Ping and make sure the network is still up and functioning...

2) Make sure SSH is running on the endpoint.

3) run `ssh -v hostname.domain.tld` in order to get a verbose output from SSH, it will help you narrow down where the connection is dying (its the host rejecting it, or are you never even making it to the host?).

Comment: On #3 here, you can add more `v`'s to the `-v` to get even more information -- like `ssh -vvv hostname`

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu doesn't ship with openssh installed. (At least the desktop doesnt)

```
sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y install openssh-server
```